# Passport wont serialize Model after saving

Tags: node.js, passport.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm working on building a basic user authentication app with passport/SQL and it seems passport is having issues serializing the model and passing it to the next request.

After posting to my sign up form and successfully saving the user (checked in SQL and confirmed row was inserted with data), I want to pass the model to Passport to serialize and use on the next page.

```
  passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      new User({
        localEmail: email,
        localPassword: User.generateHash(password)
      }).save().then(function(model) {
        return done(null, model);
      });
    });
  }));
```

It gets over here where it should be serializing it but I run into an error `Error: failed to serialize user into session`. Now this doesn't make a lot of sense because in theory, I should have passed in the newly saved user inside the save promise with `return done(null, model);`

```
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.localEmail);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(email, done) {
    new User({localEmail: email}).fetch().then(function(user) {
      done(null, user);
    });
  });
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bookshelf's model attributes are not exposed as simple object attributes, they require a `get()` method to be reached (waiting for the days we're going to have proper accessors there...)

Well, so try changing your `serializeUser()` to something like:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.get('localEmail'));
});
```

Comment: It's weird because I was still able to use `user.id` and return the correct integer. The other attributes seemed to be inaccessible though.